# Use regex to get image URL in HTML/Js

Tags: html, regex

I want to get some URLs of images in Js/HTML:

```
var a = "http://sub.domain.com/uploads/files/11-11-2011/345301-574-1182-393/2202.jpg";
var b = "http://sub.domain.com/uploads/files/23-11-2011/234552-574-2321-232/asd.png";
```

Looking for solution that will detect image url. So the output will be:

```
http://sub.domain.com/uploads/files/11-11-2011/345301-574-1182-393/2202.jpg
http://sub.domain.com/uploads/files/23-11-2011/234552-574-2321-232/asd.png
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear: You want to scan an entire HTML source file that also contains JavaScript for URL strings in the JavaScript sections?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Based off the information you've given, this should work:

```
(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))
```

You can add more extensions by adding `|ext` after `jpg`. This will allow for strings with `https` as well.

**Note**: You may want to use the *case insensitive* modifier `i` to make the capture more inclusive. This would look like:

```
/(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))/i
```

Comment: This will fail in situations like src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/images/cleardot.gif" style="background:url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/mail/sprites/general-51d583f1fd064eadd1975a8bdef3ef93.png) . What works for me is (https?:\/\/[^ ]*\.(?:gif|png|jpg|jpeg))

Comment: I think this is better:
`(http)?s?:?(\/\/[^"']*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg))`

Comment: yeah +1 : for example : someurl.svg.png (wiki eg.)

Comment: Altough @Amarsh is right, OP asked for URL, not a generic path, but URL (which I believe is required to have scheme (e.g. http: ))

Comment: If you already have `<img ...>` tag parsed out and want to get the src no matter what it contains, this worked for me `/src\W*=[^\'"]*([\'"])([^\1]*?)\1/` - `?` after `*` means "non-greedy", `\W` means non-word characters and `\1` is referencing the first defined group. Don't use `+` instead of `*` to get only non-empty - might not work if `<img ...>` has more attributes!

Answer (score 12):

A little late to the party, but in trying to do something similar to the OP, I created the following regex, which seems to handle relative links as well as absolute ones:

```
/([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/i
```

Comment: This allows extract only urls, if they are mixed with other text (very useful when you're scraping)

Comment: this does not extract filenames completely having spaces inside

Answer (score 5):

I created this regex a few days ago:

```
/^https?:\/\/.*\/.*\.(png|gif|webp|jpeg|jpg)\??.*$/gmi
```

The ones provided by others in this post work, but will not check for query strings

Example of this regex:

```js
  static checkForImage(url){
    let regex = /^https?:\/\/.*\/.*\.(png|gif|webp|jpeg|jpg)\??.*$/gmi
    let result;
    if (url.match(regex)){
      result = {
        match: url.match(regex)
      }
    } else {
      result = false;
    }
    return result;
  }
checkForImage('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/yhycJKw8ohsysnU6CBDLQPV4979oQINVmv-fRfu-jL8/%3Fsize%3D2048/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/490535372393021469/a_9e9d0e575eee0221e759257e259681af.gif')
```

Comment: Your code won't work as you expected, I'm afraid. For example, it'll match something like `https://foo.bar/a.jpg.pdf` as well or really any character after a specified extension will be a matched. I'm not regex guru, but maybe something like this will do: `^https?:\/\/.*\/.*\.(png|gif|webp|jpeg|jpg)($|\?.*$)`. You may also want to consider adding uri fragment `#` as a condition too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/"(http://[^"]*?\.(jpg|png))"/g
```

$1 is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

A super strict solution to this would be:

```regex
/(http[s]*:\/\/)([a-z\-_0-9\/.]+)\.([a-z.]{2,3})\/([a-z0-9\-_\/._~:?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%]*)([a-z0-9]+\.)(jpg|jpeg|png)/i
```

Comment: Why `(http[s]*://)`? Is there anything else besides an s that can be appended to http? oO

Comment: It's because some services misbehave if you access them via https when they don't support it, or vice versa. I have encountered instances where changing the protocol solved my issue. In any case, it was to give a different approach to other answers as well.

Comment: I know, that some services only have http, others might only have https. Oh, I see, you just use the `*` instead of the `?` which would be a little more intentional.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var regex = /(http[s]?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|gif|svg|jpeg))/i;
```

This is the result you want